# Implementing my own Collections.binarySearch method

Tags: java, arrays

Currently I am self learning java and am doing an exercise in my textbook where it asks to me to take 1000 names in a text file with corresponding phone numbers and basically ask the user what they want to search up.

What my code does right now, is uses the `Collections.binarySearch` to find Phone numbers, or to find names. However, I was wondering how I could implement my own binary search since, this chapter is basically an introduction to searching and sorting, so I figured I would learn more doing it myself.

Here are the important parts of my code

Here I use the `comparable` interface

```
public int compareTo(Item otherObject)
   {
      Item other = (Item) otherObject;
      return key.compareTo(other.key);
   }
```

I then Add Phone Numbers and Names into the ArrayLists via

```
 // Read a line containing the name
       String name = in.nextLine();
         // Read a line containing the number
       String number = in.nextLine();
         // Store the name and number in the byName array list
         byName.add(new Item(name, number));
         // Store the number and name in the byNumber array list
         byNumber.add(new Item(number, name));
```

And then call another method which does

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(byName, new Item(k,""));
   if(index<0) return null;
   return byName.get(index).getValue();
```

I also have another method which can search `byPhone`

Thus finding everything correctly.

**My Question**

What I want to know is how I can implement my own method which will do binarySearch. I've done binary search for just arrays and finding a number in an array, but I'm having difficulties really understanding how the method is going to be set up since we are dealing with objects and array lists.

For example I wanted to make a method like this:

```
int myBinarySearch(ArrayList<Item> thisItem, Object Item)
    {
            // search logic here
    }
```

However I am not sure whether this is the right approach. Could someone guide my on how exactly I should format my method for binary search, given the fact that I have a bunch of objects in an arraylist which need to be sorted, as opposed to a simple array.

**Currently Working code**

Here is the full code for my currently working method using `Collections.binarySearch`

```
/Item.java:

/**
   An item with a key and a value.
*/
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>
{
   private String key;
   private String value;
   /**
      Constructs an Item object.
      @param k the key string
      @param v the value of the item
   */
   public Item(String k, String v)
   {
      key = k;
      value = v;
   }
   /**
      Gets the key.
      @return the key
   */
   public String getKey()
   {
      return key;
   }
   /**
      Gets the value.
      @return the value
   */
   public String getValue()
   {
      return value;
   }
   public int compareTo(Item otherObject)
   {
      Item other = (Item) otherObject;
      return key.compareTo(other.key);
   }
}

//LookupTable.java:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
   A table for lookups and reverse lookups
*/
public class LookupTable
{
   private ArrayList<Item> byName;
   private ArrayList<Item> byNumber;
   /**
      Constructs a LookupTable object.
   */
   public LookupTable()
   {
      byName = new ArrayList<Item>();
      byNumber = new ArrayList<Item>();
   }
   /**
      Reads name and number pairs from the Scanner
      and adds them to the byName and byNumber array lists.
      @param in the scanner for reading the input
   */
   public void read(Scanner in)
   {
      while (in.hasNextLine())
      {
         // Read a line containing the name
       String name = in.nextLine();
         // Read a line containing the number
       String number = in.nextLine();
         // Store the name and number in the byName array list
         byName.add(new Item(name, number));
         // Store the number and name in the byNumber array list
         byNumber.add(new Item(number, name));
      }
      // Sort the byName Items so we can binary search
      Collections.sort(byName);
      // Sort the byNumber Items so we can binary search
      Collections.sort(byNumber);
   }
   /**
      Looks up an item in the table.
      @param k the key to find
      @return the value with the given key, or null if no
      such item was found.
   */
   public String lookup(String k)
   {
      // Use the Collections.binarySearch() method to find the
      // position of the matching name in the byName array list.
      // Return null if position is less than 0 (not found).
      // Otherwise, return the number for the found name.
     int index = Collections.binarySearch(byName, new Item(k,""));
   if(index<0) return null;
   return byName.get(index).getValue();
   }
   /**
      Looks up an item in the table.
      @param v the value to find
      @return the key with the given value, or null if no
      such item was found.
   */
   public String reverseLookup(String v)
   {
      // Use the Collections.binarySearch() method to find the
      // position of the matching number in the byNumber array list.
      // Return null if position is less than 0 (not found).
      // Otherwise, return the name for the found number.
     int index = Collections.binarySearch(byNumber, new Item(v, ""));
   if(index<0) return null;
   return byNumber.get(index).getValue();
   }
}

//PhoneLookup.java:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
/* The input file has the format
Abbott, Amy
408-924-1669
Abeyta, Ric
408-924-2185
Abrams, Arthur
408-924-6120
Abriam-Yago, Kathy
408-924-3159
Accardo, Dan
408-924-2236
Acevedo, Elvira
408-924-5200
Acevedo, Gloria
408-924-6556
Achtenhagen, Stephen
408-924-3522
. . .
*/
public class PhoneLookup
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the phonebook file: ");
      String fileName = in.nextLine();
      LookupTable table = new LookupTable();
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
      table.read(new Scanner(reader));
      boolean more = true;
      while (more)
      {
         System.out.println("Lookup N)ame, P)hone number, Q)uit?");
         String cmd = in.nextLine();
         if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
            more = false;
         else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
         {
            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            String n = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Phone number: " + table.lookup(n));
         }
         else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
         {
            System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
            String n = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Name: " + table.reverseLookup(n));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you write up a simple [mvce] demonstrating the problem you're having.  Nobody's going to wade through that wall of code, most of which has nothing to do with the question.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Are you asking for people to give you the code to do a binary search? It looks like it. If you have a particular problem, be specific about it, but it looks like you haven't coded anything yet to do the binary search, so better start there first.

Answer (score 1):

You can find how JDK does it from JDK source code. In `java.util.Collections`:

```
private static <T>
    int indexedBinarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)
```

Very same as the one you're working.

Answer (score 0):

A binary search is a very simple algorithm. In pseudo code, it is:

```
find(list, item):
    if list is empty
        return not found
    get middle item from list
    if item matches middle
        return middle
    else if item is before middle
        return find(list before middle, item)
    else
        return find(list after middle, item)
```

The list must be sorted to allow this to work. You can use `List.subList` to avoid having to do any copying or passing indices around.

In your case you want to be able to search by multiple criteria. It would make the most sense if you passed a argument into your method that defines what you are searching for.